# Find what Elements were added by Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net-4.0, webforms

I have got an ASP-Site, which enables the user to Add Label-Elements. I don’t know how many Labels where added or which ID they have. I know only, they will be within the Panel pnl_Added. After the user has added all his labels, he pushes a Send-Button for Update.

So, now I am at my Server, awaiting this postback, but I don’t know where, when and how to find out, which Elements were Added to pnl_Added. Can somebody help me?

I have tried something like that:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
[...]
for (int i = 0; i < pnl_Added.Controls.Count; i++)
        {
            [...]
        }
[...]
}
```

But I think it is too late because of the loaded ViewState? Is that possible?

I am working with VS 2013, ASP c#, with the .Net Framework 4.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: are you using asp.net or just asp? I'm confused because you tagged asp-classic but mentioned asp c#.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong tag!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On server, controls tree doesn't created from actual client HTML. Actually, server doesn't know anything about client HTML besides `input` tags values in scope of submitted form. In general, all controls available in `Page_Load` method, created on server side from `aspx` file markup.

To implement your scenario, you need to add hidden field for each label, added from client and save label's inner text into hidden field's value. Then you'll can get these labels texts as below:

```
var labels = Request.Form["hiddenField's name"] as string[];
```

Comment: This is not the straight way I hoped to find. But it works great. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should go one lever deeper and take the added elements from `Request` variable, because the control pnl_Added doesn't know about them as there was no postback.

Something like this:

```
Request.Form["field_id"]
```

I suggest to run the page in debug mode, review Request.Form collection and find what you need. You should see your label elements there.

Comment: You need to provide the code which adds elements, is it on client side I suppose?